# What does it mean for audio to be 'sped up'? How can I undo it?

Tags: audio, signal-analysis, sampling, sound

I very simply have a .wav audio file, but there is a note with it that says "This audio has been sped up by 10x".

I am wondering, what does it mean exactly from a signal processing perspective for an audio signal to be 'sped up' by some factor, and secondly, how can I undo this? Is it possible?

Comment: If it wasn't tempo-preserving algorithm then simply divide your sampling frequency by 10 and you are done. On the other hand, when you want to make the Alvin and the Chipmunks sound, then record a song and save it with twice or more higher sampling frequency ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could mean:

- That the metadata in the .wav file wrongly indicates that the signal was recorded at a sample rate 10x higher than the true value (for example it is advertised as having been recorded at 80kHz while it has been recorded at 8kHz). Simply fixing the metadata undoes this.
- That the signal has been downsampled by a factor of 10, but is still tagged as having been recorded at the original sample rate. This can be undone by dividing by 10 the playback sample rate (by tweaking the metadata); or by upsampling the signal by a factor of 10 without changing the playback sample rate. Note that in any case, 90% of the bandwidth of the original signal (the high frequency content) has been lost and cannot be restored (or only very approximately through [spectral band replication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_band_replication)).
- That a [time-stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_timescale-pitch_modification) (time-scale modification) algorithm has been applied to it. This is a lossy process, and cannot be undone without severe loss at such a high stretch factor. The "antidote" is simply to use any time-stretching algorithm with a stretch factor of 10x.

Comment: Hmm, well, I guess I just dont know. [Here is the file](http://www.pmel.noaa.gov/acoustics/whales/sounds/sounds_nepblue.html) and its note. I dont know which possibility it is...

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond: I am almost 100% sure that they simply saved file with 10x higher sampling frequency. That's because whales are producing very low frequency sounds, thus if we want to hear it, we must shift the pitch up. Easiest way --> cheat on sampling frequency. If you want to retrieve original signal, do the reverse, i.e. in Audacity. Aaaaa, what the heck - here is your original [**file**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33600147/nepblue_orig.wav).

Comment: I've noticed the file has a discontinuity every 400th sample, which might indicate that time-stretching has been applied simply by chopping the signal into 400 samples-long blocks, and keeping only every 10th block. This is going to be a tough case because the first thing you'll have to do is get rid of those horrible clicks.

Comment: @jojek Thanks jojek! I will look into this file...

Comment: @pichenettes Hmm, thats interesting... I guess I would not know..., what about the simply-changed-fs hypothesis?

Comment: "what about the simply-changed-fs hypothesis?". Maybe... but it won't solve the click problem. Try loading the .wav file in audacity and use "Effect/Change Speed/-90%". The annoying click can now be heard at a rate of 2 Hz - everything else is infrasound.

Comment: @pichenettes I looked at the samples, I do not see this discontinuity every 400th sample that you mentioned... where are you seeing this? (I am using original file from the website)

Comment: Nevermind, I see some of them, but not all are 400 samples apart from each other.

Comment: It looks like the waveform has been chopped every 400th sample, and that blocks have been discarded. Sometimes the "stitch" is not visible at all because the 2 blocks which have been concatenated were at the same position in the cycle. But there is definitely something "fishy" going on every 400th sample.